# Supporting RTL using semanticContentAttribute but I want one view to be as exception

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a swift app which will support LTR and RTL, so in AppDelegate I check the language and base on it, I force RTL or LTR

```
if Common.getcurrentlangauage() == Lang.AR {
     UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
} else {
     UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
}
```

It will be applied on all views in my app.
The problem is, there is one view I want to make it LTR for ever whatever the current language.

Answer (score 0):

Then

```
ltrView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

or go to that specific view in IB and make it LTR , setting the `appearance` won't change it only views with `semanticContentAttribute`  set to  `unspecified`

Comment: I tried this in viewWillAppear but didn't work

Comment: can you set it in viewDidLoad / or better in IB

Comment: does not work as I have designed custom view by code & forcing semanticContentAttribute to forceLeftToRight has no effect on it